# PHP - Edit specific HTML content in file

Tags: php

I got a HTML file containing:

```
<div>
    <p class="derp">Hello</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p>Heyo</p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to do is to update the HTML file's p-tag, with specific instructions like this:

```
<?php
    $value = "I am here to replace something!";
    $index = 1;

    $page_source = file_get_contents($file_name);
    // Something here to replace the second p-tag with $value
    file_put_contents($file_name, $page_source);
?>
```

I have tried 2 different methods to do this (loadHTML, preg_replace), but I want to hear your opinion on which might be the best fit in my situation.

Very greatful for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer [native PHP extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php). They are way faster than any other 3rd-party lib - depends on your task, but that is generally the case - and I get all the control I need over the document. [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) is the one I mostly use.

The best 3rd-party lib I have used so far, anyhow, is [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org/); it provides a jQuery-like interface to navigate through the elements of the document and it may be installed using Composer.

I would not use regular expressions, unless I had to apply a really tiny change for which creating a new instance of `DOMDocument` would seem like a waste.

Edit: [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) goes into much more details with [this amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662).